# Remove-AzureRmPolicyDefinition doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I use:

```
Remove-AzureRmPolicyDefinition -Name
```

"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/{policyDefinitionName}" and I received "True", but.... nothing was happened.
But I found walkaround ;) When I use Remove-AzureRmPolicyAssignment (!!)

```
Remove-AzureRmPolicyAssignment -Name regionPolicyAssignment -Scope '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/{policyDefinitionName}'
```

the policy definiotion was removed.

Any comments?

Comment: yeah, open the code on github and check if this is a bug. or file an issue on azure powershell github. I've used these cmdlets and doubt that there's a but in those. You probably cannot remove definition when assignments create for that definition

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a definition without assignments.

Comment: I doubt that this is a bug, i think you are misunderstanding something. I see no issues on the github mentioning this. I've used these cmdlets and they work fine. can you share a repro? complete end-to-end, to create policy definition and try and remove it

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I used full path name. Remove-AzureRmPolicyDefinition -Name {policyDefinitionName} is enough and it's works. Sorry ;]

Answer (score 1):

In this case there was no bug, just an error with input.